# How to determine if material is present at given point in 3D?

Tags: shader, godot

In Godot's material shader, how can I tell if the material occupies an arbitrary point in 3D space?

Background (in case you want more info):
I'm building a 3d third-person voxel game in Godot. I'd like the shader to hide voxels that get in between the camera and voxels that the player can move in. The voxels all happen to be on the same plane.

My plan is, for each pixel, draw a line from the camera to the plane. With some simple math I know the point of intersection with the plane. Given that intersection point, how can I tell if it hit a material or not?

Comment: Search the topic on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com - there is enough material on raycasts and rendering voxels (Edit: I'd say stencil buffer, but we are talking Godot). Also, what you want does not sound like the best approach... But I'd need to know more about you are setting up the voxels.

Comment: @Theraot Thanks. I'm using this module: http://voxel-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blocky_terrain/. I was thinking about figuring out what voxels I want to hide in Godot script, then passing an array of areas to hide to the shader, but Godot shaders dont yet support arrays. I could pass the info via a texture though... If you have a good idea about how to do it I'm all ears

Comment: The approach I have come up with is not great for Godot but should work: Render, to a separate viewport, the blocks that should be visible, with a material that outputs depth. Then in your shader materials take a viewport texture from that viewport, query it with screen UV coordinates, and and there you decide if it is infront or behind that depth. If it is in front, then you can discard the fragment. You might have to add a bias for the depth comparison.